# Is there a way to limit the distance of rioxarray's interpolate_na()

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rioxarray, xarray

I'm trying to run something similar to gdal's [fillnodata](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_fillnodata.html) command line tool in Xarray. Xarray has [interpolate_na()](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na.html) that comes with an optional parameter `limit` where you can limit the number of consecutive NaNs to be filled. However, this only works on 1-d data. Rioxarray has [interpolate_na()](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.interpolate_na) that works on 2-d data, but does not have the the `limit` parameter available. Does anybody know a work-around for this?

I've essentially got a raster with 1's and 0's. I want to convert the 0's to NaNs and extend the shape of the 1's by about 1 km around the perimeter. Maybe there's a better pythonic way to do this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fillnodata in rasterio: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.fill.html#rasterio.fill.fillnodata

On a DataArray:

```py
xds.values = fillnodata(xds.values)
```

Comment: thank you!! I was having trouble finding that!